# Manually set order of columns in pivot_table (Pandas plot) when order of index is allready set manually

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

txt = '''Category    COLUMN1         COLUMN2     COLUMN3    
A          0.5               3          Cat1   
B          0.3               5          Cat1 
C          0.7               4          Cat1
A          0.4               3          Cat2
B          0.8               5          Cat2
C          0.3               4          Cat2
'''

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+")

order = ['Cat2', 'Cat1']


col1 = pd.pivot_table(df,index='COLUMN3',columns='Category',values='COLUMN1').loc[order].plot(kind='bar')





plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.3, 0.5))

plt.show()
```

Which yields the following result:

[image: Columns are ordered alphabetically]

Using `loc[order]` I manage to override the order of the `index` as desired.
However the order of the `columns` is automatically sorted alphabetically as can be seen on the above picture.

I want to override the automatic sorting here as well. so that I achieve the following:

[image: Override the second ordering]

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to reorder the columns of your dataframe to be `["B", "A", "C"]` instead of `["A","B","C"]`. This is easily performed by indexing the dataframe with the columns you want.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

txt = u'''Category    COLUMN1         COLUMN2     COLUMN3    
A          0.5               3          Cat1   
B          0.3               5          Cat1 
C          0.7               4          Cat1
A          0.4               3          Cat2
B          0.8               5          Cat2
C          0.3               4          Cat2
'''

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+")

order = ['Cat2', 'Cat1']
suborder = list("BAC")

df2 = pd.pivot_table(df,index='COLUMN3',columns='Category',values='COLUMN1').loc[order]
df2 = df2[suborder]
df2.plot(kind='bar')

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.3, 0.5))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That is really great, highly appreciated! I didn't think of sorting the dataframe itself. As an additional comment: In the cases when `A = string1`, `B = string2`, `C = string3` one just adjusts suborder to be: `suborder = ['string2', 'string1', 'string3']`. This has been tested and works very well.

Comment: Yes, `suborder = ["B", "A", "C"]`, this is what the anwer does, right?

Comment: Yes exactly it does exactly that.